# Algebraic Compact manifold originates from a proper scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, analytic-geometry

If $M$ is a compact complex manifold, which is the analytification of some scheme $X$ of finite type over $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$, then must $X$ be proper over $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Do you know the characterization of proper as a correspondence between field extensions and specializations along a valuation ring? Apparently this will implies the answer yes. Note that your scheme will be a complete algebraic variety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

See SGA 1

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206203

Exposee XII, Proposition 3.2.(v), page 245 (261 in the pdf).